# Bombarding molecules with electrons

Tags: electrons, molecules

I have been reading a book titled "High Voltage Engineering". It seems to me that in this book it is considered that in a gas when they collide an electron with a molecule, the molecule is stationary and the electron is not. This is because the $v_\text{molecule} \ll v_\text{electron}$.

What do you think about this?

Comment: Welcome!  Is this in the context of particle accelerator?  If so they are likely accelerating the low-mass electron to a high velocity rather than accelerating the molecule.  From a standpoint of relativity (think Galileo, not Einstein) it would seem that it is ambiguous and irrelevant which is moving and which is stationary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome. The subject focuses on electric discharges in gases, they effectively plan to bombard a gas with electrons to generate ionization  by collision of their molecules.

Comment: So, I think all they are saying is that the molecular movement under the experimental conditions (i.e. temperature, pressure)  is negligible compared to the high-velocity electrons bombarding the "stationary" (in the bulk sense) gas.  In this case, the velocity in which the molecules collide can be approximated as the velocity of the electrons alone.

Comment: A molecule moves with thermal speed. An electron having enough energy to ionize a molecule (that is, at least few eV) moves much faster than that.

Comment: Exactly, but could you assume something like that or not?

Comment: As @IvanNeretin says, yes, it has to be so in order for ionization of the gas to happen.  In other words, if that weren't true, nothing would happen, electrons would just meander through the gas molecules and no reaction/ionization would take place.

Comment: Room temperature is about 23 meV (milli-electron Volts). One can easily make 100keV or higher energy electrons. Clearly the electrons will be moving much faster than the gas molecules. They are even moving much faster than a 100keV ion. (Also, remember that the rest energy of an electron is 511keV, so that 100keV electron should be treated relativistically).

Comment: @JonCuster Interesting point of view, recommend some bibliography for this topic?

Comment: Almost any intro plasma physics book will cover the relative mobilities of electrons vs ions. Look at the simplest system - a hydrogen plasma. The electron has roughly 1/2000th the mass of a proton. If electrons and ions are in thermal equilibrium, the electrons will have a velocity 40x that of the ions. Heavier ions will have even slower relative velocities. And, that assumes thermal equilibrium, which generally does not hold for plasmas.

Comment: @JonCuster ty :)